# « Se souvenir » et « se rappeler » avec « quand »

Tags: prépositions, conjonctions, subordonnées, verbes-pronominaux, pronoms-interrogatifs

> Je me souviens/rappelle quand j'étais petit. La vie était simple.

Est-ce correct d'utiliser *se souvenir* ou *se rappeler* avec *quand* de cette manière ? Un [dictionnaire](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/se-souvenir) a *se souvenir de* et *se souvenir que*, alors je ne suis pas sûr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On se **rappelle quelque chose** mais on se **souvient de quelque chose**.

La première phrase devrait donc être :

> *Je me rappelle quand j'étais petit. La vie était simple.*

et la deuxième :

> *Je me souviens de quand j'étais petit. La vie était simple.*

Cependant, "*se souvenir de quand*" semble plus du domaine du français parlé. La forme suivante est plus littéraire :

> *Je me souviens de mon enfance. La vie était simple.*

On peut aussi écrire :

> *Je me souviens, quand j'étais petit, la vie était simple.*

Références:

[Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/se-rappeler-quelque-chose-se-souvenir-de-quelque-chose)

[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2881)

Comment: Je ne suis pas vraiment d'accord. Je me souviens d'elle, est parfaitement correct. Et il y a même une différence de sens entre Je me souviens d'elle, et je me rappelle d'elle. Dans le cas de se rappeler, ça semble demander un effort de mémoire supplémentaire en quelque sorte.

Comment: @Quidam Oui, bien sûr, *je me souviens d'elle* est parfaitement correct. Je n'ai jamais affirmé autre chose. Ce qui serait incorrect est *je me souviens elle*.

Comment: Ah pardon, mal compris alors. Oui, c'est une exception, j'ai ouvert un post pour demander des explications sur la règle Je me souviens d'elle.

Comment: Pourquoi le vote à une réponse tout à fait correcte ?

Comment: @Dimitris I wonder (pure speculation — I would not downvote) if it's related to the fact behind this observation in the OQLF article cited: "Par ailleurs, on a pris l’habitude d’employer *se rappeler* avec la préposition *de* sur le modèle de *se souvenir de*." Depending on how commonplace « se rappeler de » is (incidentally, that's what I learned to say here in Canada), perhaps someone was put off by the categorical statement that it's simply an error. I sometimes get frustrated on ELL — which is why I gradually stopped reading it — by people saying one doesn't say things one often says...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Exactly. I tried but couldn't downvote my reply so I edited it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Je me souviens/rappelle **de** quand j'étais petit.

ou

> Je me souviens/rappelle **que** quand j'étais petit **,** la vie était plus simple.

Dans cette situation, "que" implique qu'une explication/information suit.

Comment: Je ne suis pas non plus d'accord. Je me souviens quand j'étais petit, est correct. De nombreux exemples dans la littérature, et pas trouvé de règles qui disent le contraire: Se rapporter au livre de Georges Pérec, je me souviens...Je me rappelle de quand, ne me semble pas très correct par contre.

Comment: Je me souviens que quand j'étais petit = correct. Par contre, je me rappelle que, je ne sais pas. Le verbe se rappeler a une construction particulière, voir http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/dictee/2017/03/25/37005-20170325ARTFIG00004-se-rappeler-de-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php

Answer (score -1):

Je me souviens quand j'étais petit = correct.

La construction normale du verbe se rappeler se fait directement, sans mot de liaison.
Sauf dans le cas particulier d'un pronom personnel: je me rappelle d'elle.

Je me rappelle la mer.
Je me souviens **de** la mer.

Oui, ça semble un peu bizarre, mais apparemment:

Source: http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/dictee/2017/03/25/37005-20170325ARTFIG00004-se-rappeler-de-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php

à mon avis, étymologiquement, se rappeler signifie re-appeler un souvenir à sa mémoire. 
Cela semble actif.

Se souvenir, semble un peu plus passif, et plus nostalgique (mais ça dépend aussi du contexte). On fait appel à un souvenir en image en quelque sorte.

Se rappeler est souvent utilisé pour une situation plus urgente, en conséquence.

Je me rappelle que je dois appeler le dentiste.
Je me souviens que j'ai donné un billet à ce petit garçon pour Noël.

Pour la phrase en question, bien que se rappeler ne doive pas être foncièrement faux (?),
je trouve l'utilisation de se souvenir, sans ambiguïté, et meilleure. Au moins, on est sûr qu'elle est correcte, et la connotation nostalgique de *se souvenir* est parfaite dans l'exemple.

Comment: Et comme toujours, des downvotes sans expliquer la raison. C'est tellement mieux.

Comment: Les downvotes s'attaqueraient-ils à l'utilisateur davantage qu'à la réponse? On trouve facilement des réponses pires que celle-ci sans vote négatif sur le réseau.